# Why can I run cargo in github actions without setting it up?

Tags: docker, rust, github-actions, rust-cargo

I have a GitHub workflow with job like this:

```yaml
docker:
    name: Docker image
    needs: test-n-build
    runs-on: ubuntu-20.04
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up QEMU
        uses: docker/setup-qemu-action@v1

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v1

      - name: Set docker image tag
        if: startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/')
        run: echo "DOCKER_TAG=:$(cargo read-manifest | sed 's/.*"version":"\{0,1\}\([^,"]*\)"\{0,1\}.*/\1/')" >> $GITHUB_ENV

      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: ${{ startsWith(github.ref, 'refs/tags/') }}
```

This workflow builds docker image and pushes it to registry if tag pushed to branch. As seen there are a `Set docker image tag` step with cargo command used, but when I'm copy-pasted things I forgot to add setup rust action. But that step successfully executed and no error like `command cargo not found` not appears.

Is it because that job needs `test-n-build` job where I actually setup Rust, or QEMU installs Rust? How it finds `cargo` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see on the [Ubuntu-20.04 virtual environment](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/main/images/linux/Ubuntu2004-Readme.md), it is provided with some Rust Tools installed:

```markdown
### Rust Tools
Cargo 1.58.0
Rust 1.58.1
Rustdoc 1.58.1
Rustup 1.24.3
```

Therefore, you wouldn't need any extra setup to install them in that case.

You can check the available virtual environment used as runners and their configurations [here](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments#available-environments).